# every Espresso "perform" gives same error: "cannot be called on the main application thread"

Tags: android, android-espresso

Writing the first instrumentation tests for an existing application's activities. The first test I've written errors out saying about `onView(...).perform(typeText(...), closeSoftKeyboard())`

> Method cannot be called on the main application thread

here's the test so far:

```kotlin
class LoginActivityTests {
    @get:Rule var rule = ActivityScenarioRule(LoginActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun whenClickLoginStoresDomainInConnectionManager() {
        val domainName = "foo"
        val scenario = rule.scenario
        scenario.onActivity {   
            onView(withId(R.id.domainEditText)).perform(typeText(domainName), closeSoftKeyboard())
        }
    }
}
```

The error is thrown on the `onView` with abbreviated stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method cannot be called on the main application thread (on: main)
at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks.checkState(Checks.java:111)
at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks$1.checkNotMainThread(Checks.java:150)
at androidx.test.internal.util.Checks.checkNotMainThread(Checks.java:130)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.postAsynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:1)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:4)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:8)
```

I've looked at sample tests for performing clicks and text typing, and none of them seem to use any explicit specification of UI threads or anything. They just do what I've done: annotate a non-suspend function as `@Test` and then invoke `onView(...).perform(...)`

I even tried to explicitly run in UI thread:

```kotlin
it.runOnUiThread {
                onView(withId(R.id.domainEditText)).perform(typeText(domainName), closeSoftKeyboard())
                onView(withId(R.id.loginButton)).perform(click())
                Log.d(TAG, "performed click")
            }
```

Same error, same line. I've also installed android.test:rules and put `@UiThreadTest` on my `@Before` (even though there's not any UI stuff there, apparently the annotation can only take effect on After and Before methods.

**Edit** Question is: how do I get `perform` actions to work in my tests? Why am I getting this error when all the sample tests I'm finding with `perform` actions never have to specify UI thread or anything?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to run it inside of the activity scenario, instead of just letting the rule implementation handle it? (That's how my tests run -- just `onView(...)...` inside of the @Test function.)